# Where and how store List<myClass> with preferences?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with columns and I need to store column name, width and color properties of this `DataGridView` when my form is closed, and restore them when form is loaded.
Should I use for this purpose application settings (Settings.settings file) or I should use another file?
And if I choose to store in application settings how can I serialize this information?
Example of the data:

```
class ColumnInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public Color BackColor { get; set; }
}

List<ColumnInfo> needToStore;
```

Comment: I think the question you want to ask is, "In general, for this application, how do I want to persist things?". And we would need a whole lot more information about what you are doing to answer that question.

Comment: You can save your data in a database or in a file. When you load the form, simply load your data into the grid.

Comment: @apostrofix I think there is no utility to use databae to store some UI settings and it is recommended the use of the application setting.

Comment: In settings, you can store a serialized XML string. If you want more specific or detailed advice than that, you should post the question so that it's more specific. Figure out for yourself what it is exactly you want to do, and then ask specific questions about any problems you might encounter with implementation.

Comment: tag ColumnInfo with [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). then use the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not considering the case of serializing to some file or database. Just application settings. You could store your data as `string` or `StringCollection` out of the proposed types. First decision would be choosing a serialization type out of `XmlSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter`, protobuf or even `DataContractSerializer`. Second would be how to turn a byte array to a string (base64 or some encoding).

[image: Serialize list to a string]

Code only for xml serialization, rest of formatters similar (see picture):

```
    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ColumnInfo>));
    xs.Serialize(ms, needToStore);
    Properties.Settings.Default.String = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Deserialization, for example, binary formatter:

```
byte[] bytes=Convert.FromBase64String(Properties.Settings.Default.String);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
  {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    return (List<ColumnInfo>)bf.Deserialize(ms);
  }
```

If you chose `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` instead of `System.String` as the container of your data then you'd have to go back and forth from `ColumnInfo` to `string`:

```
public static explicit operator string (ColumnInfo ci) { return ci.ToString(); }

public static explicit operator ColumnInfo(string s) { return ColumnInfo.FromString(s); }
```

serialize like:

```
 foreach (string s in needToStore.Select(ci => (string)ci))
  {
    if (! Properties.Settings.Default.StringCollection.Contains(s))
      Properties.Settings.Default.StringCollection.Add(s);
  }
```

deserialize:

```
  List<ColumnInfo> columnsInfo = new List<ColumnInfo>();
  foreach (string s in Properties.Settings.Default.StringCollection)
  {
    columnsInfo.Add((ColumnInfo)s);
  }
```